Climate on an outer system exomoon heated by tidal heating
A question related to this question: Making a moon habitable through tidal heating

Imagine a large moon (>0.25 earth masses) of a gas giant with low insolation (>5AU from a sun-like star) that has a surface ocean of water (not subsurface), volcanoes, archipelagos and small landmasses. The tidal heating from the gas giant provides enough heat to the moon to keep the water ocean liquid; along with help from natural outgassing of greenhouse gases such as carbon dioxide, water vapour, hydrogen and methane.
How would the climate behave on a moon like this with its low insolation? Would it have a monoclime climate or would the temperature vary significantly every time the moon orbits its parent gas giant and/or due to resonant neighbouring moons?

The way you wrote it, your  planet looks like tidal friction heats the ocean and s/th else (e. g. radioactivity) drives volcanism. In Real Life, all sources contribute heat to all the thermodynamic activity indiscriminately (neglecting insolation).

The largest influence on the temperature of such a moon is likely going to be resonant neighbours. The seasons would be dictated by the tidal flexions caused by the interactions with the orbits of other large bodies going around it's parent gas giant rather than necessarily by its own orbit.
The large input of energy caused by resonant passes isn't going to be immediately apparent, the tidal flexion and heating is going to occur deep beneath the surface and be expressed at the surface after some delay by increased geothermal action bringing that heat to the surface. Seasons will therefore be caused by heat convection rather than surface irradiation and will occur at times that are predicable only with a detailed knowledge of the orbital dynamics of the gas giant moon system AND an understanding of the migration of tidal heat through to body of the moon.
Surface heating won't be uniform but nor will there be polar tundras, rather the climatic zones, such as they are, will be randomly distributed according to any heterogeneity in geothermal heat emanations. So you can have tropical rift valleys where a lot of heat is locally pumped out of the ground and much colder tablelands where heat is very slowly conducted out through thick crustal rock. Otherwise the climate would be fairly globally uniform.

Thank you for the recent edit, clarified things a lot. Over the longer term, would it be possible for the moon’s global climate to shift between ‘refrigerator periods’, ‘temperate periods’ and ‘sauna periods’ over centuries/millennia due to increases or decreases in tidal friction (due to slight orbital variations around the gas giant)?

@casualworldbuilder I would expect it to go through short-term "seasonal" variations based on it's interactions with the other moons around it, the Ganymede-Europa-Io systems cycles every 7days or so. And I'd expect some longer term cycles based on perturbations in orbital periods, and eccentricities such that resonant distances, and thus tidal forces, change over time but you're not talking about a huge amount of energy flux under any conditions so the average temperature is probably only going to fluctuate by at most a couple of degrees, ice ages on Earth are ±5°C or more.

@casualworldbuilder Those longer cycles aren't going to be easily predictable as they're going to be the sum of the gravitational interactions of every celestial body in that particular star system.

Ah, that’s disappointing from a Worldbuilding view but understandable. Perhaps in my idea notes I’ll alter a few things. Maybe the gas giant and it’s moon will be in an S-type binary system. The influence of a nearby companion star could cause long term climate cycles in the monoclime climate of the moon that may be both more rapid and greater in amplitude, shifting between warming and cooling the planet/moon by several °C every ~1000 years? This perhaps deserves a whole other question but I want to see if I could have that effect on the moon while keeping the moon monoclime in the short term.

@casualworldbuilder Slightly off-topic, but binary systems probably wouldn't have that effect. This is because the second star in the system is actually also at a constant distance from the first. An unstable trinary system may do so, however. A good example of this is Trisolaris in the Three-body problem series.

@casualworldbuilder That is a whole different question and I'm probably not the one to answer it, astrophysics/orbital mechanics is not my strong suit, but there some very good contributors who can help with that one.

@Bubbles When I thought binary system I was thinking the stars would have an eccentric orbit around their barycentre so that their distances would vary. During periapsis, the other star would influence the climate of the moon enough to cause a ‘sauna period’ and during apoapsis, the opposite occurs. Tidal heating alone maintains an average temperature but the eccentric binary star setup could allow long term climate shifts over centuries/millennia (while maintaining short term climate stability).

Gravitational interactions between a gas giant and a large close moon would quickly (in astronomical time scales) regularize the orbit of the moon.
The elliptical orbit of the moon would quickly be circularized until it was almost circular, except if there were other large moons orbiting the planet.  If there were other large moons orbiting the planet their orbital interactions would tend to make their orbits more elliptical.
The plane of the Moon's orbit might originally be at any angle to the plane of the planet's equator, but the gravitational interactions would pull on the plane of the moon's orbit until the moon was orbiting in the planet's equatorial plane.
The moon's axis of rotation might originally be at any angle to the axis of rotation of the planet. Tidal interactions between the moon and the planet would slow down the rotation of both worlds and push the moon farther from the planet.  The Moon would move away from the planet until it became tidally locked.  And at the same time the tidal interactions would change the tilt of the moon's axis of rotation, until the moon's axis of rotation was parallel to tha tof the planet, and the moon's equatorial plane was in the planet's equatorial plane.
Tidal interactions between the planet and any other moons would have the same effects on the other moons, thus slowly changing their obits.  So if other moons of the planet are large enough and close enough for their tidal interactions with the moon in question to be significent, the strength of those tidal interactions and their effect on the moon in question would slowly change over time.
Season in the atmosphere of the gas giant planet would depend on how elliptical the orbit of the planet was, and what the axial tilt of the planet's rotation was compared to the plane of the planet's orbit.
If the planet had a highly elliptical orbit the changing distance to the star and the changing amount of radiation the planet received from the star would be important in determining the temperatures in the planet's atmosphere.
Since the moon would share the orbit of the planet, and the semi-major axis of the moon's orbit would be a tiny fraction, probably much less than 1 percent, of the semi-major axis of the planet's orbit, the moon would share the distance of the planet from the star, and would exeprience almost exactly the same changes in illumination by the star as the planet experienced.
On planets which have only slightly elliptical orbits, the main cause of seasons are the axial tilt of the planets, like in the case of Earth.
And as said above, the axial tilt of the moon should be the same as the axial tilt of the planet, so if the planet's orbit around the star was almost circular, the main determination of seasons on the moon would be the axial tilt of the planet and the moon.  As a general rule, you would expect the seasons to be opposite on the northern and southern hemispheres of the moon at any one time, just as they are on Earth.
Except that most of the heat necessary for the moon to be warm enough for liquid water using life would come from the interior, from tidal heating, and not from illumination from the star.
Thus any changes in illumination from the star due to an elliptical orbit or to the axial tilt of the moon would have comparatively minor effects on the surface temperature of the moon.  And what effects they did have would happen over the course of one planetary orbit around the star, so each "season" due to changing stellar illumination - assuming it was noticeable - should last a few Earth years.
But there would be one important effect of those seasons if your moon is supposed to  have a breatheable oxygen rich atmosphere produced by photosynthesis.  Plants will need sufficient light from their star to produce oxygen thorugh photosynthesis.
And the illumination from a sun-like star at a distance of 5 AU will be about 0.04 as strong as the illumination which Earth receives from the Sun. So maybe the moon will have seasons which don't depend on the temperatrure but on changing light levels.  When there is enough light for photosynthesis in a region, the plants grow and create food and oxygen, and when there is not enough light, the plants are dorment.
One thing which could change the internal heat coming to the surface of the moon, might be various tidal interactins between the planet, the moon in question, and any other moons of the planet large enough and close enough to cause significent tidal heating.
And in that case the amount of tidal heating on the moon's surface might vary a bit as the strength of various tidal interactions changes with varying distance.  The synodic periods between specific orbital configurations may drive cycles of higher and lower surface temperatures.

“And in that case the amount of tidal heating on the moon's surface might vary a bit as the strength of various tidal interactions changes with varying distance. The synodic periods between specific orbital configurations may drive cycles of higher and lower surface temperatures.”
Would these temperature variations occur everywhere in the moon at once? If so, how would wind and ocean currents be affected as it would probably be different from solar-driven climate patterns.

I will assume that the planet and moon have mostly circular orbits.
Seasons are going to be pretty much nonexistent here since the main source of heating is not from the star, but rather tidal heating. Also, the moon itself will act as a heat reservoir, making any seasonal changes to the temperature on the surface unlikely(The core of the planet will still be really hot for a while after the source of the heating as stopped). Since the heat is pretty much all coming from the center of the planet, the climate will likely be monocline. Radiation from the gas giant may have an effect but is likely to be negligible in terms of heating. Also, moons in orbital resonance will allow the tidal heating to continue for a long time, but from my research don't do that much heating themselves when compared to its parent planet, so that will also not have much of an effect. Overall, the climate will be mostly the same everywhere, and not change that much seasonally.
TL;DR It'll likely be a monocline climate with only small variations in temperature, and not subject to significant seasonal change.

I’ve received a lot of very good answers but this one is the closest to what I was looking for so far. I also would go by this assumption, although resonant neighbouring moons (if they exist and are large enough) would probably lead to a moon-wide variation in the monoclime temperature to some degree overtime with their slight orbital changes, assuming heat pipe tectonics on the habitable moon, would you agree?

@casualworldbuilder From what I looked at, I had got the impression that moons in orbital resonance keep the orbits elliptical(required for tidal heating), but don't contribute that much to the heating themselves when compared to its parent gas giant.

Exactly. Apologies for the confusion. Would the heat vary at all in the moon during its spin-orbital period (as it makes periodic alignment with sibling moons)? And would that heat be all over the moon at once or in specific regions? Or perhaps if the orbit itself changes slightly over longer periods of time, the moon might go through ‘chill-house’, ‘temperate-house’ and ‘hot-house/steam-house’ periods?

@casualworldbuilder Moons with orbital resonance are required to keep the orbits elliptical enough for tidal heating. However, the alignment of other moons will not make a significant difference in the climate, it'll only give a small boost to the orbit. As for the orbit changing over time, this is also not likely. It would require a large change in its orbit, probably requiring a close encounter with another moon. While this is possible, it will hardly be periodic or even regular if the system is stable.

@casualworldbuilder It is unlikely for the moon's orbit or interactions with other bodies to cause long-term shifts in climate. Possible close encounters with other bodies might alter its orbit enough, but this will be extremely rare. However, there are plenty of other things that could cause long-term changes in climate. An easy one is greenhouse gases in the atmosphere, which happens to be what causes ice ages here on Earth. Another alternative is the parent planet itself having a long-period elliptical orbit, allowing the star to play more of a role in heating the moon.

Io, Jupiter’s third largest moon, has similar features to your moon. However, it lacks a surface ocean. Ionian temperatures vary widely. The average surface temperature is -130°C (-202°F). The volcanoes, on the other hand, can reach 1,649°C (3,000°F).
A surface ocean would prevent that kind of fluctuation. With this in mind, I could imagine this moon having a monoclime climate.
Earth’s oceans regulate its climate. The average temperature on Earth is 15°C (59°F). The surface ocean would probably give your moon a similar temperature.

You need good insulation on your moon to keep the heat. And therein lies the tightrope. If you lose too much atmosphere to biological processes, space - the heat escapes to fast and the moon becomes a snowball with a frozen out atmosphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth
If you have to good isolation, you get Venus-like cooked alive atmosphere.
Volcanism can replenish your greenhouse atmosphere, so you can bring you back from ice-age to the tropics in a relatively short time. Also very active tectonics could squeeze out "oil" or reignite coal stored in lower layers. Asteroids can contribute to get back from the tipping point too. Its a very unstable set of affairs similar too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clathrate_gun_hypothesis
