How much Methane could reasonably exist on a world with 6% (60,000 ppm) Oxygen in the atmosphere?
Let’s say I have a world that has an atmosphere similar to both Titan (lots of Nitrogen and organic compounds) and Earth during the Boring Billion. Oxygen is present on this world, but only about the same as the level found on Mount Everest’s summit (~0.06 atm partial pressure). The world itself receives less sunlight than Earth and is kept warm by tidal-heating.

If I also want Methane on this world to be present (through methanogenic-producing life and volcanism), how much Methane could co-exist with that level of Oxygen on geological time scales?

A curious associated question was asked on our sister site, Astronomy.SE. But I wonder (and I'll wait for one of our chemists to explain it) if the combustion equation CH4 + (3)O2 -> CO2 + (2)H2O doesn't mean you can't have a significant amount of free oxygen in a primarily methane atmosphere. (Lightning and volcanism would be bad.)

6 per cent of what?

@AlexP Oxygen partial pressure in the atmosphere (about Mount Everest summit levels of Oxygen).

Are you asking if it can be a whole number percentage of the atmosphere? If you're looking for answers in parts per billion it's not answerable without additional information about total methane output.

@gs whole number percentage yes, or equivalent to 60,000 ppm

@casualworldbuilder I meant the methane.

@gs Oh. That’s what I’m trying to figure out. How much Methane can exist for long periods of time in an atmosphere with Mount Everest summit-levels of Oxygen?

Where there is Oxygen, Methane, and Life there are Methanotrophs.
Methane is believed to be the oldest source of energy used by life here on Earth.  Chemically speaking, it's one of the most straight forward molecules to turn into a power source. As such, it is a reasonable assumption that any planet that has oxygen, methane, and life will either start of with methanotrophs or very quickly evolve such lifeforms.
Here on Earth, our oceans and soil are full of microbes that consume atmospheric methane and thier populations are kept in check by scarcity. So, even if our planet were to suddenly start producing 100s or even 1000s of times as much Methane over time, our atmosphere would still never exceed methane concentrations larger than a few parts per million because it would just cause a bloom of methanotrophs that would grow in numbers until present concentrations restabilize or the atmosphere runs out of Oxygen.
Also, More Methanogenic Life Needs More Sunlight
Methanogenic life is only prevalent on Earth because of the decomposition of organic molecules that are more complex than methane.  Methanotrophs have to consume more methane in thier lifetime to build thier complex molecules than can be reclaimed during the decomposition process; so, it has to be through the effort of photosynthetic life that you add a positive net sum of Methane to the atmosphere.  Since you planet is described as darker than Earth, then the sum of its life forms should gather less photosynthetic energy and therefore produce less total methane than Earth based life can.  So, yes, you can design your planet to produce more methane using volcanoes, but probably but not through biological processes.

Trace gas.
Combustion is irrelevant here as Starfish Prime points out. Photodissociation of methane may be significant but we can probably ignore it to get an upper bound based solely on the oxygen. You'll get atomic oxygen radicals at about 1/10 the rate on Earth (a bit less O2 x a bit less UV insolation). The reaction of free O radicals with water gets OH radicals. The reaction of OH radicals with CH4 removes most of the CH4 that gets removed from the atmosphere.
Constraint: life is producing oxygen at a rate sufficient to maintain 6% partial pressure no matter what else we change.
So assuming a similar amount of atmospheric water, methane will have about 10 times the mean lifetime as on Earth. Meaning that if it is produced at the same rate as on Earth (which seems correct since you state that life is a main source) you have about 10 times the methane as Earth. Add an order of magnitude or two if you want for super-volcanos and really stinky life: worldbuilding math is napkin math.
Earth methane is less than 1 part per million, so you have between 10 and 1000 parts per million. Since you've set your atmosphere to the same pressure as Earth (by expressing partial pressures and percentages as the same value), that's a partial pressure between 0.001% and 0.1%.

Excellent answer. I expressed partial pressures and percentages as the same value just for ease answering the question. I believe 1% Methane should also be enough to produce a haze assuming that value is higher than 1/10th the level of Carbon Dioxide in the atmosphere.

@casualworldbuilder a bit less excellent... in my haste I accidentally added an order of magnitude at the end when converting from ppm to %. Editing.

Oh. Would 0.1% still be enough for the haze? Also, a previous answer implied more than a percent could remain in the atmosphere for millions of years. I’m still trying to evaluate what would be a ‘plausible’ maximum.

@casualworldbuilder I dont know about a haze. I think SP did not adequately consider the oxygen. Unless your story is about meteorology, I think that having the characters be surprised that the methane partial pressure is too high for their models and then get on with beingRobinson Crusoe in space or however your plot runs is all the justification you need.

I’m still in just a brainstorm phase. I have just gotten answers for these questions: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/258967/climate-on-an-outer-system-exomoon-heated-by-tidal-heating https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/259197/precipitation-on-an-outer-exomoon-heated-by-tidal-heating and I want to consider the kind of life and atmosphere my world would have in small steps.

As luck would have it, not only are the magic numbers here well understood, but people have even made pretty diagrams of it:

(source: wikiwayman via wikipedia)
note: this stuff isn't entirely independent of pressure, so the above diagram presumably represents behavior under STP.
The short red line at the bottom left of the diagram marks the limiting oxygen concentration, in this case 12%. Below this proportion of oxygen, you can't trigger an explosion, regardless of what proportion of the atmosphere the fuel makes up.
This implies that at STP, an atmosphere with 6% oxygen could be 94% methane and no bad things would happen, so long as the proportion of oxygen did not continue to rise over time.

how much could co-exist with that level of Oxygen on geological time scales?

There are at least two problems with the "geological timescale" request (though I guess the quaternary period is only a few million years long, and that counts as geological).
Firstly is photodissociation of methane under UV light from your star. This forms tholin hazes which can tint your atmosphere a thick, soupy, orangey-brown. If the atmospheric methane isn't replenished by some source over time, it will eventually be depleted by this effect. In the presence of oxygen, you'll also get carbohydrates and CO2 coming out of this... I don't know if this could accelerate the process, but it could cause an interestingly nutritious rain for primitive life.
The second issue is the evolution of aerobic methanotrophs, who basically only have to just sit in your atmosphere to be bathed in easily digestible food and oxygen. Over a long enough timescale, there seems like there'd be a good chance of all that methane becoming water, CO2 and free hydrogen blowing into space. That rather depends on the oxygen and methane supply, of course... photosynthesis won't work at its best under a thick layer of tholin smog.
There are two many variables there for me to offer any further opinions, though.

Very good answer. By ‘geological time scales’ I was trying to imply that it would be in the atmospheric composition quasi-permanently - self-sustaining.

@casualworldbuilder "quasi-permanently" is still kinda underdefined ;-) Millions of years... sure. Billions though? Seems harder. Seems like it would a need quite unusual ecosystem... aerobic methanotrophs are pretty voracious on Earth, and methanogens don't work well in places with too much oxidizing stuff. I suspect that having oxygen and methane together is an ecologically unstable situation in the long term, with something evolving to tip the balance one way or another.

Haha I suppose for worldbuilding purposes, millions of years is okay. I don’t mind having some fluctuations in the atmosphere over time - perhaps methanogenic and oxygen-producing life forms compete with each other for dominance; leading to periods with higher concentrations of methane and periods with slightly higher concentrations of oxygen. This would also lead to fluctuations of warmer and cooler climate across the world. This may also occasionally produce a Titan-like haze during more methanogenic periods. Does this seem plausible enough?

@casualworldbuilder you'll get a tholin haze whenever there's a non-negligible amount of methane in the atmosphere. Its just unavoidable. Titan only has ~6% methane, so unless you're going to have a mostly neutral (eg. nitrogen or maybe CO2) atmosphere its gonna be pretty brown.

Most of the atmosphere will be Nitrogen with a bit of Carbon Dioxide. I think the Methane haze would start to form once Methane reaches levels higher than 1/10 Carbon Dioxide levels.

@casualworldbuilder saying the world goes through periods of methanotroph and methanogen dominance does not make sense because methanotroph populations will always adjust to methanogen output.  You might get short lived, regional spikes of one or the other lasting for up to about 10 years, but the system will be very stable at geological time scales.
